# jmeter - how to record request contains 5000 items

Tags: jmeter

I recorded jmeter scripts for a request having 5000 items, in that each time some rids will change, and it is impossible to change the rids or to add regular expression extractor for 500 times.
Please help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you no need to record all the HTTP requests for the resources (items). Just add one HTTP request which is responsible for loading the resources and configure it as follows:

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Add HTTP request (sampler) which is responsible to load resources.
2. Go to Advanced tab
3. Enable "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" checkbox.
4. Enable "parallel Downloads" checkbox
5. in Number field, specify "6" (so, 6 threads will be used to download resources. this is to simulate browser behaviour)

**Note1:** use latest JMeter version i.e.., 3.1 which supports CSS parsing. This enables the JMeter to send requests which are orginiated from .css files.

**Note2:** still .js parsing is not supported (as of 3.1 version). so, requests originated from .hs files won't be sent.